# SQL Server BULK INSERT error

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

This is my source data in CSV format:

```
4,23,2AY5623,7235623
4,23,2GP1207,1451207
4,23,2GQ6689,4186689
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [idCodeLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idFirm] [int] NOT NULL,
    [valCodeFrom] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [valCodeTo] [varchar](15) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This the code I am using to bulk import:

```
USE Test
GO

TRUNCATE TABLE Table1
GO

BULK INSERT Table1
  FROM 'C:\Temp\test.csv'
  WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    MAXERRORS=0,
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  )
GO
```

Error I am getting is:

> *Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (idCodeLevel).*

Can you please someone tell me why is it failing?

I googled and found out that I might have to use the format .fmt. But how can I convert a csv file to fmt. I have seen code to create fmt file from sql table.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What happens if you take out the 'ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'' line?

Comment: Hmm.... what **version** of SQL Server are you using? I cannot reproduce this - works just like a charm - on SQL Server **2008 R2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the csv have a row at the top of field names? If so you'll need to add "FIRSTROW = 2" to your bulk statement. If not, try creating a new table that is all VARCHAR fields, then check the data: you probably have something strange in your data that you aren't expecting, like a non-printing character. Import as text and then try something like "SELECT ISNUMERIC([FIELD1]) FROM NEWTABLE".

Comment: I did not have any thing other than the data in the first row (as mentioned above). But adding "FIRSTROW = 2" worked. Really really weird. But It loaded everything except the first row. So, i made a fake first row and ran the bulk insert and it loaded every thing. THANKS SO MUCH> killed an hour atleast on this.

Comment: @user1666952 I suspect that you've got a UNICODE Byte Order Mark, or some other invalid character at the beginning of your text file that just happens to be invisible to Notepad.  Such a character would of course be invalid for an integer field, so you would get a conversion error.

Comment: Weird - there must be a hidden character in there somewhere. I'd just make sure that first row of actual data is, in fact, in your imported data!

Answer (score 0):

use the sql import wizard to import data from external file.

Right click on database--->task--->import----> specify the flat file as source and select the destination server.

for more information please visit [Import CSV data to SQL](http://c--shark.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-use-sql-server-2008-r2-import.html)